# Is a state machine the best solution

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture, state-machine

Currently I am trying to redesign/refactor an existing application which is currently implemented as a state machine, but I'm not sure, if this design pattern is the best solution for this kind of job.

Scenario: **Configure devices**

*Devices (sensors) have to be configured before they could be used. We have a Java EE Application, where a user starts a configuration process for a device. Then messages are send between the device and the application. At the end, the device is configured (or in a Error/Timeout state) and a report to an external system is send.*

Currently the process is made as a state machine, where the current state is saved in the database. If a message is received from the device, the saved state is retrieved and the next message is send to the device -> next state. If a device doesn't answer, a timer sends a Timeout Message -> next state (timeout)

What do you think? Is the state machine pattern, really fits to this scenario? Or which design could fit better?

Thx,
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine for me, another alternative could be using a bpm but I think that is intended for another kind of things.